# Calling an ARM assembly function from C results in segmentation fault

Tags: android, c, assembly, segmentation-fault, arm

I am teaching myself some ARM assembly, but I can't even get a simple program to run.
I set up a toolchain and everything and my code compiles just fine. However, when I execute my program from **/data/local/tmp/** on a Galaxy Nexus with Android (the only platform I am testing on), I always get a 'Stopped (signal)' and/or '139 Segmentation fault' (usually without the number). This happens the moment I try to call an assembly function from C code.

**neontest.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void neon_test(void); // I also tried variations like extern, but no avail

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("\nHello World\n"); // works just fine
    neon_test(); // segmentation fault
    printf("Done!");
    return 0;
}
```

*(The neontest.h file is currently empty)*

**neontest_neon.s:**

```
.text // added because some wiki said so
.arch armv7a
.fpu neon
.thumb
.syntax unified

.align 4
.global neon_test
.func neon_test
neon_test:
    NOP
.endfunc

.end
```

I fear that this is a rights issue, but I have no idea how to even properly identify the problem beyond this point.

Comment: Should'nt there be at least a ``ret`` in your function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution that works in most cases:

### Use a debugger

It will show you the exact location where the bug happens and it's usually more or less clear what happened.

That said, here's a couple of guesses:

1. You indeed forgot a return (`BX LR`) as @hivert says.
2. Thumb functions must be marked with [`.thumb_func`](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/ARM-Directives.html) so that the linker handles it properly. Just `.thumb` is not enough.

Comment: Yes, I really have no excuse for not using one. Somehow, BX LR got eaten up in my tries to make it work and I never realized it was gone. Thank you, and hivert and 11temp, too!

Comment: Igor, I just spent all day wrestling with the `.thumb_func` issue -- I believe it's more subtle. `.thumb_func` is necessary for linking *function pointers*, not simply functions themselves. For example, the interrupt vector table is a table of function pointers. Linking a custom handler requires `.thumb_func`, while linking any plain-old assembly function to be used in the program does not. And of course this is for thumb-mode only.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from function with a proper asm instruction. On ARM cortex m3 its 
bx lr
instruction, not sure what is the right one for your platform.